# How to print custom date format in Twig?

Tags: theming, 8, datetime

How can I print a custom date format in Twig?  First of all my I am trying to edit the `field.html.twig` of the field called `field_publication_date`, in that file I find this variable `{{ item.content }}` which prints   `Jun, 12/06/2016 - 12:29`.

This is what I have tried: `{{ item.content.field_publication_date|format_date('M') }}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Try to use this** -

```
{{ item.content.field_publication_date|date("M") }}
```

But, I think you will get your solution in

```
{{ item.content|date("M") }}
```

Where `item.content` contains the date string inside **field--node--field-publication-date.html.twig**.

Comment: `format_date` should be the function, referencing a date format from Drupal

Comment: Got referenced from here- http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

Comment: Thank you. The first option worked for me {{ item.content.field_publication_date|date("M") }}

Comment: If it is a date field, why aren't field formatter settings sufficient? Also if it is a timestamp, format_date is a Drupal twig filter you can pass custom date formats to: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates

Comment: @kevin I pretended to use display suite and by token show the dates in different divs. But somehow the custom date didn't work for me.

Comment: how to format when item is multiple? Is that same way?

Comment: Hi. I tried the first one : `|date("M")` but I got an error stating : `DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in DateTime->__construct() (line 497 of vendor\twig\twig\src\Extension\CoreExtension.php).`

Answer (score 24):

First, create the custom date format `my_custom_date_format` in the configuration section of the drupal admin.

Second, use the `format_date` Twig filter, like here:

```
{{ node.created.value|format_date('my_custom_date_format') }}
```

It might be necessary to convert the date to a unix timestamp, first. That will look like this:

```
{{ node.my_date_field.value|date('U')|format_date('my_custom_date_format') }}
```

Comment: The second code example didn't work for me, since "value" on the content array (content.field_date.value) was null. I suspect it shows up or not based on the display formatter used for that field. I had to use `node.field_date.value|date('U')` instead.

Comment: @George is right, the `.value` key is usually only available for fields from entities like `node`, `user` or `paragraph`, but not within render arrays (`content`). I edited the 2nd example to use the `node` variable

Answer (score 5):

The `\Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItem` has a value and a date property. The `value` is UTC and the `date` is computed. Use the date property to avoid having to deal with the timezone, and you can use a created format or a custom one:

`{{ node.field_publication_date.date|format_date('custom', 'F j, Y') }}`

Date format in Drupal:

`{{ node.field_publication_date.date|format_date('my_custom_date_format') }}`

Comment: Here's what worked for me: {{ node.field_event_date.date|date('U')|format_date('custom', 'F j, Y') }}

Comment: Hi @arnoldbird, can you explain me what `date('U')` does ?

Comment: @AmanDevrath is for Unix Time Stamp

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked when setting a datetime attribute on a time element. the closest was @Marcos Buarque's answer.

Instead of a formatted date, the rendered output would either print the unix timestamp or a wrongly-formatted date like "2020-09-03ADT00:00:00".

In order to get the proper format for a full date time, I couldn't use `Y-m-d\TH:i:s` or `Y-m-dTH:i:s`. I needed to split the format into two variables. This is probably some quirk with format_date and twig.

```
{% set htmlDate = node.getCreatedTime|format_date('custom', 'Y-m-d') %}
{% set htmlTime = node.getCreatedTime|format_date('custom', 'H:i:s') %}
<time datetime="{{ htmlDate }}T{{ htmlTime }}">{{ date }}</time>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question refers specifically to formatting the value of a given date field, but I needed to format the date the node was created. In case you need that, this is what works for me (after trying several different options):

```
{{ node.getCreatedTime|format_date('medium') }}
```

This is where I got this solution from: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2016-02-17/how-to-get-formatted-node-creation-date-in-d8#comment-10865464

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The date value with twig's own date() format function:

```
{{ content.field_arrival_date.value | date("Y/m/d") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert from a DateTime string (e.g. `2022-03-03T01:53:06`) in UTC to the current timezone, I had to use:

```
{{ (datetimeStr ~ '+00:00')|date('U')|format_date('medium') }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your **Authored on** date format in your custom node twig

`{{ item.content|date("F j, Y") }}`

You will get the result like this  **January 30, 2023**